# How to host a webApp with a Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET web application that does some calculations using a Web Service. I have two questions about hosting it locally on my machine through IIS.
First, Do I need to host the two projects, the Web App and the Web service ? I have tried to host the web app but when I tried to run it was not able to connect to the web service. 
Second, how would I make this web App accessible to the people within the company network only?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

```
1.) Create web service.
2.) Paste your web service bin ==> Debug Content in IIS if already set it up(IIS).
3.) Set Framework in application pool(IIS).
4.) (Click Web Service Site Created(IIS)) == >Set up Browsing Directory to enable.
5.) select .asmx file(right click) ==> Browse.
6.) Web Service is already running.
7.) Get the Link of your Web Service copy and paste into (9 step).
8.) create vb.net/c# project.
9.) Right Click references tab of your vb.net/c# Project ==> Add Service Reference paste web service url in address textbox == > Go.
10.) Create service reference name ==> ok.
11.) you have your web service now at your project.
```

Comment: Any problem, don't hesitate do ask.